# Angular 2 setting height in animation callback

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2.0.1.

I'm trying to create an accordion component were regions collapse and expand via animation. The content inside the accordion is dynamic and can be any height -- so I also want to offer the ability to set a height to a particular accordion content that gets enforced by the animation. (Say, `400px`)

For the animation I'm toggling between `height: '0px'` and `height: '*'`.

I then figured, using animation callbacks, I could set the height on a particular accordion content on `start` (and `done`).

This sort of works, and this is where the issue comes in -- when I expand the area it *first* goes to its full height and *then* sets itself to 400px.

On collapse it *first* sets itself to full height and then works its way down.

Here's an example (just press the button):
http://plnkr.co/edit/Etn2qTZ7APZBXmf4Ws5H?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

What can I do in order to not have the animation jump like that?